# Roundcube Plugins brick install

Tags: php, mysql, roundcube

Hello all I am running Roundcube 1.0.2RC and I am having issues with plugins. I edited the config.inc.php file with the following:

```
$rcmail_config['plugins'] = array(
'cpanellogin',
'cpanellogout',
'markasjunk',
'userinfo',
'vcard_attachments',
'jqueryui',
'database_attachments',
'autologon',
'rccalendar',
'serverinfo');
```

and it causes round cube to no longer load. I have tried one at a time, I have tried using only one of each by commenting out. Nothing works. If I use one the whole thing stops working. The ones that are most important are the cPanel ones. When a user logs in though webmail on cPanel they have to login again to round cube. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was simple. It was character encoding on TextEdit for my Mac that caused the issue. The above posted code was edited and is now correct and working.